# AppSecret key lifetime and expiration

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, oauth, token

I see when I use Seller Dashboard max token lifetime is 3 year.
Does anybody know it how long it be valid if I use AppRegnew.aspx page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found answer on official MSDN documentation
[How to: Replace an expiring client secret in an app for SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn726681.aspx)

> Client secrets for apps for SharePoint that are registered using the
>   AppRegNew.aspx page expire after one year. This article explains how
>   to add a new secret for the app.